# in django, how to allow users to log in using their twitter accounts

Tags: python, django, authentication, web, oauth

I just want to use the social auth to help people login to my website, i do not want to make my own register app, so in my website's database, it only has a table contains 2 cols, there are uid and twitter-id.If a user has connected to my website, the table will contains his profile. I don't need to make more cols at the table. I think it is enough for me.

But how to check if a user is login or not ?

I can get the access token and session-id from twitter, but what should I do next?
if I get a session-id, how to keep it and verify the user at my website?

Comment: django social auth takes care of all this for you.

Answer (score 2):

A contender to the more established auth apps are https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Answer (score 1):

Try [django social auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/), it has support for many social networks and auth providers.